# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule' on VS Code Windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I am using Python on VS Code (Windows). I am encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\taimo\Documents\Visual Studio Code Workloads\Python VS Code\DateTimeModule.py", line 1, in <module>
    import schedule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'
```

I have tried many things to fix this issue, which include changing the Python interpreter in VS Code, updating the Python version on my computer, installing "scheduler" using pip3, uninstalling and reinstalling scheduler using pip3, however even after all this the issue has not been fixed.

It is infuriating, because a few days ago, it was working just fine without any errors, and today it suddenly started throwing this error. I shall be very grateful to you if you can solve this problem for me.

Thanks in advance!

The code I am running is:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: what python version are you using ?

Comment: @McLovin 3.10.7

Comment: One reason I can think of is , the python version for which the module is installed and the python version from which you are running the module are different. Can you open python with terminal and import there ?

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, yet the error persists. Moreover, I have checked the Python version using sys.version as well. My interpreter and sys.version are both 3.10.7. Yet the issue persists.

Comment: @McLovin The import in the terminal is also returning the same error.

Comment: Can you check what all version your computer has ?

Comment: @McLovin for some reason, it has now started working. Once I started running it by "Run Python File". Before, it wouldn't execute upon that. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of error is basically caused by the existence of ***multiple*** python versions on the machine.

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python:Select Interpreter** --> Choosing the correct interpreter resolves the error.

Your best bet is to use a virtual environment, which manages python versions and various packages nicely.

1. Use the following command in the vscode terminal to create a virtual environment

   ```
   python -m venv .venv
   ```
2. Select the interpreter in the virtual environment

   [image]
3. Create a new terminal activation environment

   [image]
4. Install `schedule` package in virtual environment

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem. I just have a minor confusion. Should I use a virtual environment for all of my Python programs, no matter how big or small?

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful to you, you can change the status of the answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. Using a virtual environment can better manage python versions and various packages. But it's just an interpreter environment, which has nothing to do with your project, you can switch interpreters for your project at any time. As long as the interpreter environment you choose has the required packages installed, your program will run.

Comment: For example, if your project is meals, then the virtual environment is the dishes. You can always replace the dishes you want to use. As long as your dishes can hold food, then you can eat.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your python `/site-packages` folder is added to `PATH`. Also, it is recommended that you have a separate environment for you to install libraries specific for a project.

Comment: I am sorry, it is still returning the same error.